# Why are some 7digital songs not available in the Ubuntu One Music Store?

Tags: ubuntu-one

Not all of the music from 7digital is available in the Ubuntu One Music Store.
As an example: The band "I am empire" is not listed but if I search the same in the 7digital store, I can find it.

So what's the reason for that?

Comment: I couldn't find an answer to your question in the [Ubuntu One Music Store FAQ](https://one.ubuntu.com/help/faq/#music-store), but it was interesting to see that [pre-existing 7digital acounts cannot be merged with Ubuntu One Music Store accounts](https://one.ubuntu.com/help/faq/can-i-merge-my-7digital-and-ubuntu-one-account/). Perhaps what you noticed is part of the reason why this is so.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, running the Ubuntu One Music Store is not quite as simple as reselling the entire 7digital catalogue: you will only see a particular song in the U1MS if we have permission to sell it in your region, and our set of licenses is not as extensive as 7digital's.

The music industry is still breaks up the world into separate regions for the purpose of marketing and licensing, so the selection of songs we offer differs from country to country too.  The following FAQ entry describes which labels we have distribution agreements with in the different regions:

https://one.ubuntu.com/help/faq/what-regions-of-the-world-are-able-to-purchase-songs/

So presumably the song you are after is outside of any of the existing distribution agreements.